# Gif Animation is not working as expected in WPF

Tags: wpf, gif

I am having one multi thread WPF application. In that application am using gif image with one of the threads. I need to check whether database connection is established or not ,until then the icon should be loading gif, after that which will turn into success or failure icon accordingly.
[image]

I have used the following code to set the gif initially .

```
 <Image x:Name="sample" Grid.Row="1" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding  DataBaseImageSource}"  Margin="{Binding ElementName=BorderContainer, Path=Margin}"  />
```

After that i am changing the icon using below code. This code will get executed after window.show() method.

```
try
        {
            myContext.Database.Connection.Open();
            myContext.Database.Connection.Close();
           this.DataBaseImageSource = (BitmapImage)Application.Current.FindResource("SuccessIcon");
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            this.ResultSummary = "Failure";
            this.DataBaseSummary = e.Message.ToString();
            this.DataBaseImageSource = (BitmapImage)Application.Current.FindResource("ErrorIcon");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
```

once i called this above window.show() method, then am changing the animated source based on the database availability .

But the gif is not at all loading it behaves like a normal png image, after that the image gets changed based on the result. how can i make gif to be animated  followed by source change?

Comment: try add  `gif:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="Forever"`

Comment: Please show how you handle `DataBaseImageSource` in code behind. Also, I'm slightly worried about your remark about threads.

Comment: @grek40 i Have added the logic to handle the DataBaseImageSource property.

Comment: If I interpret your code correctly, you are executing the database open in the UI thread, so the UI will just freeze until the operation is completed. You should try to use some async code and perform the database connection in a separate Task.

Comment: @grek40 i tried async code and it worked perfectly, thanks.